# Unity 3D animation messing up character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, fbx

I have a character model in my 3D Unity game which currently only has 1 animation in the animation controller. When I try to add a new animation, even if it is not playing the character suddenly starts floating upward!
You can see in the screenshot below that the IDLE animation is not playing, only the run animation is playing, but my character is just floating up. If I remove the idle animation then the character just runs without floating. Both of the animations are .fbx files and I didn't edit them, or the animator controller except for adding a parameter to make it play the idle animation which was not set to true.
[animator controller during play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKjmm.png)

Comment: When you say it floats upward, is this a continual float where if you keep idling it just keeps going up? Or does the idle just appear to not touch the ground? It might be an issue with your import settings and/or the actual frames themselves. If it continually moves up, in the Animator did you accidentally change a field on your Rigidbody or some other component that can change your position over time?

Comment: It floats upwards while doing the run animation. I figured out the problem was the idle animation which makes it float up but I still don't get why the players was floating up even though the idle animation was not playing.

Comment: It is very hard to say without seeing code or the Animator. There are a lot of reasons why something can float up for what seems like no reason.